# Rig Veda Translation : Rudra name omitted ( Book 8 Hymn 63 )

Tags: rig-veda, rudra

Using only the Griffith ,  Book 8 Hymn 63 Mantra 12 , I read : ([Griffith)](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv08063.htm)

> अस्मे रुद्रा मेहना पर्वतासो वर्त्रहत्ये भरहूतौ सजोषाः | यः शंसते
> सतुवते धायि पज्र इन्द्रज्येष्ठा अस्मानवन्तु देवाः ||
>
> asme rudrā mehanā parvatāso vṛtrahatye bharahūtau sajoṣāḥ | yaḥ
> śaṃsate stuvate dhāyi pajra indrajyeṣṭhā asmānavantu devāḥ ||

But in the translation Rudra is disappeared..

> 15 The very truth do I declare to thee, Paruṣṇī, mighty flood. Waters!
> no man is there who gives more horses than Savistha gives.

Since there is a big degree of interpretation , would be interesting to have a complete hymn reference to interpolate to the Griffith. Why RudrA is omitted?

Comment: BTW RudrA and Rudra are not the same and the mantra has RudrA in it.

Comment: RudrA has a different meaning. You can see -- https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=rudrA&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3

Comment: Thanks for the link. But even now using the alternative translation is out of context from the Griffith.

Comment: According to one translation,  **rudrā** does not indicate the vedic god Rudra, but his sons Maruts.  Maruts are known to move alongwith Indra and thus, the rishi is calling maruts to come along with Indra, as their chief.

Comment: @Rickross "rudrA" is plural of "rudra". You know, the group of divine beings called the "rudras".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rig Veda VIII.63 is dedicated to Indra, except the last 12th Mantra.

The translation given by Stephanie W. Jamison and Joel P. Brereton is as follows;

> For us are the Rudras [=***Maruts***] in their profusion and the mountains
> of one accord at the Vr̥tra-smashing, where the call is “Carry (the
> day)!”
>
> The steadfast one who has been established for the praiser and
> presser—with him, ***Indra, as their chief*** let the gods help us.

rudrā does not indicate the vedic god Rudra, but his sons Maruts.
Maruts are known to move alongwith Indra and thus, the rishi is
calling maruts to come along with Indra, as their chief.

Edited

As per the OP's request, the translation of remaining 11 mantras from the same Hymn and from the same source, has been posted.

> 1. The tracker [=Agni?], stationed in front, has been smeared with the intentions of the great ones [=gods], he on whose doors father Manu
>    smeared insightful thoughts to the gods.
> 2. The stones with soma on their backs have sat up, as if to the measure of heaven. The solemn words and sacred formulations are now to
>    be recited.
> 3. Indra, knowing how, uncovered the cows for the Aṅgirases. That manly act of his is to be praised.
> 4. As of old, let Indra, strengthener of poets, fortifier of speech, the kindly one, come among us for help at the pouring of our chant.
> 5. And therefore, following the intention of your will, those eager to sacrifice (have cried out) “hail!”; their chants have cried out to
>    (you), who are swollen with strength, Indra, to give of the cowpen.
> 6. All heroic deeds, both done and to be done, are in Indra, whom the chants know as the very ceremony itself.
> 7. When cries were sent surging to Indra by the clan belonging to the Five Peoples, through the power of their inspiration, through the
>    power of his measure he laid the strangers low. He is peaceful
>    dwelling.
> 8. Here is the praise that follows you: you did these manly deeds; you furthered the turning of the wheel.
> 9. (Viṣṇu) strode widely to the rice porridge for this bull to live on. (Indra) took it, as cattle do barley.
> 10. Seeking help as we present this (praise hymn), through you (all) might we have skill as our father for the strengthening of the one
>     accompanied by the Maruts [=Indra].
> 11. Yes indeed! through our chanters we cry out again and again for your establishment according to the ritual sequence, o champion. Let
>     us conquer with you as our yokemate, Indra.

Comment: Interesting, although the degree of difference between the two translation leave a conspicuous margin of interpretation. Would you kindly post the entire translation of the Hymn for a complete reference? Thanks!

Comment: The Hymn VIII.63 contains a total of 12 mantras, out of which 12th one had already been posted.  Do you want the meaning of remaining 11 mantras? @LuckyPashu

Comment: yes from the same source pls! Griffith is getting more than older, archaic.

Comment: Can you edit your question suitably, so that I can add the meaning of  remaining 11 mantras? @LuckyPashu

Comment: i edited the question accordingly

Comment: My answer has since been updated please @LuckyPashu

Comment: great , thank you!